# Using If-Else ladder to find greatest of four numbers entered

Tags: python

(absolute newbie here and to coding in general so please bear with me)

I was tasked to find the greatest of four numbers entered by a user in a python program.

I used the following syntax to do so...

```
a = int(input("enter first number"))
b = int(input("enter second number"))
c = int(input("enter third number"))
d = int(input("enter fourth number"))

if(a>b, a>c, a>d):
    print(a)

elif(b>a, b>c, b>d):
    print(b)

elif(c>a, c>b, c>d):
    print(c)

else:
    print(d)
```

This did not work.

However, when I worked with only the 'if' condition in the above ladder, it worked as expected. It didn't print 'a' when a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4 and it did print 'a' when a=4, b=3, c=2, d=1. I tried more combinations of four numbers and the code worked just as I intended it to.

How come the full syntax isn't working as it did with only the 'if' condition in place?

What's another way to accomplish the task?

EDIT: I made a mistake while observing my program at work. When I used only this portion of the code.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4

if(a>b , a>c , a>d):
      print(a)
```

The program does print 'a' in such cases too. Sorry if the original post caused any confusion. Thanks to @chepner whose response prompted me to go through the program again.

Comment: how exactly do you expect `(a>b, a>c, a>d):` to be evaluated?

Comment: I suggest spending some time with [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: If you want an `if/elif` ladder like this, you need to construct each condition correctly. Did you mean: `if a>b and a>c and a>d:`?

Comment: Your first condition will always be true, because `(a>b, a>c, a>d)` is an expression that creates an non-empty tuple of Boolean values, which itself is always truthy.

Comment: What *exactly* did you do when you "worked with only the 'if' condition"? What code did you use then?

Comment: @UnholySheep, I thought "  (a>b, a>c, a>d):  " would work the way print() would've worked in a situation where a = "apple"
b = "banana"
c = "cat"
d = "dog"

print(a,b,c,d).  Here, the print() function gets applied on all four variables (a, b, c and d). But I realized I should've used 'and' instead of the commas. Thanks.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ,  post updated, pls check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = int(input("Enter First Number: "))
b = int(input("Enter Second Number: "))
c = int(input("Enter Third Number: "))
d = int(input("Enter Fourth Number: "))


if a > b and a > c and a > d:
    print(a)
elif b > a and b > c and b > d:
    print(b)
elif c > a and c > b and c > d:
    print(c)
elif d > a and d > b and d > c:
    print(d)
```

You should be using **and** when comparing through several conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like consider any number as max and then simply compare rest numbers to find max among them

```
max_ = a
if b > max_:
    max_ = b
if c > max_:
    max_ = c
if d > max_:
    max_ = d
print(max_)
```

Comment: I was looking for a method that uses only the if-else ladder and 'and', 'or' and 'not' operators. I'm trying not to learn too many functions and operators etc. at once. This method is really easy but I can't make use of it for completing my task. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `max`:

```
print(max(a, b, c, d))
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to add the user input to a list and use `max` to find the max

```
lst = []
for i in range(0,4):
  x = int(input("enter a number:"))
  lst.append(x)

print(max(lst))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import math

def maximumoffour(i,j,k,l):

m=max(i,j,k,l)

print("Maximum of the given four numbers",i,j,k,l, "is",m)

i=eval(input("enter the value 1 :"))

j=eval(input("enter the value 2 :"))

k=eval(input("enter the value 3 :"))

l=eval(input("enter the value 4 :"))

maximumoffour(i,j,k,l)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.